# How to read data from xml file which is stored insdcard?

Tags: android

I am trying to read data from an xml which is stored at sdcard.
So, I used XmlResourceParser in my code but how can I provide my xml file to XmlResourceParser?
Is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File myXmlFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myfiles/myxml.xml");
And try to read data from File...
```

Comment: It would be better to use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) in combination with [getExternalStorageState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29) instead of hard-coding the value.

Comment: Thanx. It is little bit useful to me.